# Apex tests failed while upgrading the app version

Tags: community, appexchange

When I am trying to release a new version of the existing application, it fails with the following error:

> One or more Apex tests failed. Resolve the test failures, then upload again.

[image]

I see the following when I click on the method name:

[image]

How can I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no reports in the packaging org where Format = 'Summary'. You could either add one in that org to satisfy the test, or you could rewrite the test to handle that scenario.

Even if you fix the test in this org, it could still fail in customer orgs and you may well find yourself fielding support calls about it. Writing tests as an ISV is a pain because you never know the shape of the org your code is running in.